Encrypting Variables in Airflow
Is there a way for me to encrypt these JSON files in Airflow? Specifically, to change the values in the "Is Encrypted" column from False to True. Thanks a lot
I have tried searching for information in the Airflow documentation. It is related to the FERNET_KEY, but I do not know the specific steps to handle it.
here are my variables

To set the is_encrypted flag to True, you must enable Fernet encryption. Setup the Fernet key in the Airflow configuration file (airflow.cfg) under the [core] section:
[core]  
fernet_key = your_fernet_key

To generate a Fernet key, you can use the following command (Make sure you have the module installed):
python -c "from cryptography.fernet import Fernet; 
print(Fernet.generate_key().decode())"

After setting the Fernet key, restart Airflow. Any new variables you create will be encrypted, and the is_encrypted flag will be set to True.
